# php error: The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, mcrypt

I have a login and sign up form and use the encrypt library to encrypt the password.. I am using Xampp for my server and my system works correctly..

code to encrypt the password:

```
$this->encrypt->encode('my password');
```

add encrypt library

```
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('encrypt');
```

and setting the secret key in config:

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'nmsc encrypt secret key';
```

My code works well using xampp server in windows but when Im trying to upload my website to ubuntu server I've got an error says

> The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension

how to fix that problem? refering this guide https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html but I dont know how to install that mcrypt. my website needs to run from ubuntu server. how to install or fix that problem?

Comment: You should not use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard padding (PKCS#5 or PKCS#7) and uses null padding which will not work correctly with binary data. Instead consider either [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor-php](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php) for a full secure solution.

Comment: CodeIgniter 3 provides a different encryption class that does most if not all things right. Use that if you have access to codeigniter 3.

Comment: Passwords must be **hashed**, NOT encrypted. Use https://secure.php.net/password

Comment: This answer worked for me.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54334312/8889610

Answer (score 27):

Best solution is (only available for CI 3 and up):

change

```
 $this->load->library('encrypt');
```

to

```
 $this->load->library('encryption');
```

Comment: Please mention file name also

Comment: Does it work with CI4?

Answer (score 17):

Save this code to libraries/Encrypt.php

It must to be work!

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * CodeIgniter Encryption Class
 *
 * Provides two-way keyed encoding using XOR Hashing and Mcrypt
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Libraries
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html
 */
class CI_Encrypt {
    var $CI;
    var $encryption_key = '';
    var $_hash_type = 'sha1';
    var $_mcrypt_exists = FALSE;
    var $_mcrypt_cipher;
    var $_mcrypt_mode;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Simply determines whether the mcrypt library exists.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->_mcrypt_exists = ( ! function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        log_message('debug', "Encrypt Class Initialized");
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Fetch the encryption key
     *
     * Returns it as MD5 in order to have an exact-length 128 bit key.
     * Mcrypt is sensitive to keys that are not the correct length
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function get_key($key = '')
    {
        if ($key == '')
        {
            if ($this->encryption_key != '')
            {
                return $this->encryption_key;
            }
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $key = $CI->config->item('encryption_key');
            if ($key == FALSE)
            {
                show_error('In order to use the encryption class requires that you set an encryption key in your config file.');
            }
        }
        return md5($key);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the encryption key
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */
    function set_key($key = '')
    {
        $this->encryption_key = $key;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Encode
     *
     * Encodes the message string using bitwise XOR encoding.
     * The key is combined with a random hash, and then it
     * too gets converted using XOR. The whole thing is then run
     * through mcrypt (if supported) using the randomized key.
     * The end result is a double-encrypted message string
     * that is randomized with each call to this function,
     * even if the supplied message and key are the same.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  the string to encode
     * @param   string  the key
     * @return  string
     */
    function encode($string, $key = '')
    {
        $key = $this->get_key($key);
        if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === TRUE)
        {
            $enc = $this->mcrypt_encode($string, $key);
        }
        else
        {
            $enc = $this->_xor_encode($string, $key);
        }
        return base64_encode($enc);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Decode
     *
     * Reverses the above process
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function decode($string, $key = '')
    {
        $key = $this->get_key($key);
        if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\+=]/', $string))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $dec = base64_decode($string);
        if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === TRUE)
        {
            if (($dec = $this->mcrypt_decode($dec, $key)) === FALSE)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $dec = $this->_xor_decode($dec, $key);
        }
        return $dec;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Encode from Legacy
     *
     * Takes an encoded string from the original Encryption class algorithms and
     * returns a newly encoded string using the improved method added in 2.0.0
     * This allows for backwards compatibility and a method to transition to the
     * new encryption algorithms.
     *
     * For more details, see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html#encryption
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   int     (mcrypt mode constant)
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function encode_from_legacy($string, $legacy_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $key = '')
    {
        if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === FALSE)
        {
            log_message('error', 'Encoding from legacy is available only when Mcrypt is in use.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        // decode it first
        // set mode temporarily to what it was when string was encoded with the legacy
        // algorithm - typically MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        $current_mode = $this->_get_mode();
        $this->set_mode($legacy_mode);
        $key = $this->get_key($key);
        if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\+=]/', $string))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $dec = base64_decode($string);
        if (($dec = $this->mcrypt_decode($dec, $key)) === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $dec = $this->_xor_decode($dec, $key);
        // set the mcrypt mode back to what it should be, typically MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
        $this->set_mode($current_mode);
        // and re-encode
        return base64_encode($this->mcrypt_encode($dec, $key));
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * XOR Encode
     *
     * Takes a plain-text string and key as input and generates an
     * encoded bit-string using XOR
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _xor_encode($string, $key)
    {
        $rand = '';
        while (strlen($rand) < 32)
        {
            $rand .= mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        }
        $rand = $this->hash($rand);
        $enc = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $enc .= substr($rand, ($i % strlen($rand)), 1).(substr($rand, ($i % strlen($rand)), 1) ^ substr($string, $i, 1));
        }
        return $this->_xor_merge($enc, $key);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * XOR Decode
     *
     * Takes an encoded string and key as input and generates the
     * plain-text original message
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _xor_decode($string, $key)
    {
        $string = $this->_xor_merge($string, $key);
        $dec = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $dec .= (substr($string, $i++, 1) ^ substr($string, $i, 1));
        }
        return $dec;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * XOR key + string Combiner
     *
     * Takes a string and key as input and computes the difference using XOR
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _xor_merge($string, $key)
    {
        $hash = $this->hash($key);
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $str .= substr($string, $i, 1) ^ substr($hash, ($i % strlen($hash)), 1);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Encrypt using Mcrypt
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function mcrypt_encode($data, $key)
    {
        $init_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_get_cipher(), $this->_get_mode());
        $init_vect = mcrypt_create_iv($init_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return $this->_add_cipher_noise($init_vect.mcrypt_encrypt($this->_get_cipher(), $key, $data, $this->_get_mode(), $init_vect), $key);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Decrypt using Mcrypt
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function mcrypt_decode($data, $key)
    {
        $data = $this->_remove_cipher_noise($data, $key);
        $init_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_get_cipher(), $this->_get_mode());
        if ($init_size > strlen($data))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $init_vect = substr($data, 0, $init_size);
        $data = substr($data, $init_size);
        return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt($this->_get_cipher(), $key, $data, $this->_get_mode(), $init_vect), "\0");
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Adds permuted noise to the IV + encrypted data to protect
     * against Man-in-the-middle attacks on CBC mode ciphers
     * http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/GLOSSARY.HTM#IV
     *
     * Function description
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _add_cipher_noise($data, $key)
    {
        $keyhash = $this->hash($key);
        $keylen = strlen($keyhash);
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0, $j = 0, $len = strlen($data); $i < $len; ++$i, ++$j)
        {
            if ($j >= $keylen)
            {
                $j = 0;
            }
            $str .= chr((ord($data[$i]) + ord($keyhash[$j])) % 256);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Removes permuted noise from the IV + encrypted data, reversing
     * _add_cipher_noise()
     *
     * Function description
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   type
     * @return  type
     */
    function _remove_cipher_noise($data, $key)
    {
        $keyhash = $this->hash($key);
        $keylen = strlen($keyhash);
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0, $j = 0, $len = strlen($data); $i < $len; ++$i, ++$j)
        {
            if ($j >= $keylen)
            {
                $j = 0;
            }
            $temp = ord($data[$i]) - ord($keyhash[$j]);
            if ($temp < 0)
            {
                $temp = $temp + 256;
            }
            $str .= chr($temp);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the Mcrypt Cipher
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   constant
     * @return  string
     */
    function set_cipher($cipher)
    {
        $this->_mcrypt_cipher = $cipher;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the Mcrypt Mode
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   constant
     * @return  string
     */
    function set_mode($mode)
    {
        $this->_mcrypt_mode = $mode;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Get Mcrypt cipher Value
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  string
     */
    function _get_cipher()
    {
        if ($this->_mcrypt_cipher == '')
        {
            $this->_mcrypt_cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
        }
        return $this->_mcrypt_cipher;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Get Mcrypt Mode Value
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  string
     */
    function _get_mode()
    {
        if ($this->_mcrypt_mode == '')
        {
            $this->_mcrypt_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
        }
        return $this->_mcrypt_mode;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the Hash type
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function set_hash($type = 'sha1')
    {
        $this->_hash_type = ($type != 'sha1' AND $type != 'md5') ? 'sha1' : $type;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Hash encode a string
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function hash($str)
    {
        return ($this->_hash_type == 'sha1') ? $this->sha1($str) : md5($str);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Generate an SHA1 Hash
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function sha1($str)
    {
        if ( ! function_exists('sha1'))
        {
            if ( ! function_exists('mhash'))
            {
                require_once(BASEPATH.'libraries/Sha1.php');
                $SH = new CI_SHA;
                return $SH->generate($str);
            }
            else
            {
                return bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA1, $str));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return sha1($str);
        }
    }
}
// END CI_Encrypt class
/* End of file Encrypt.php */
```

Comment: thanks, i m getting error in my code on  godady server  but but this solution work.

Answer (score 14):

You should install the PHP mcrypt module;

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

And normally you will be good ;)

Comment: Im not using ubuntu to develop my project, is there any way to install that php5-mcrypt from windows using xampp? my school is using ubuntu server.

Comment: I'm not a windows user, but i found this link that might be helpful for you http://www.myoddweb.com/2010/11/18/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-windows/

Comment: But I must advise you to switch to Linux. ^^

Comment: Don't forget to reload apache after doing this: `service apache2 reload`

Answer (score 12):

I was getting this error because i had switched from  XAMPP(php5) to XAMPP(php7),
for this I replaced my old CI->system->libraries->encrypt.php with new file here:[encrypt.php](https://github.com/kpushpendra81/exam/blob/master/encrypt.php), and it worked.

In this new file we check if mcrypt_encrypt is supported or not in __construct function with code below

```
   $this->_mcrypt_exists = ( ! function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

and based on that we use different function between mcrypt_encode and _xor_encode like that.

Just to know, if you see this old file in __construct function you will see actual error checking

```
    if (($this->_mcrypt_exists = function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) === FALSE)
    {
        show_error('The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension.');
    }
```

It worked for me.

Comment: THIS works, cause it repairs wrong PHP functions that were designed  for PHP 5.x in such old systems like Codeigniter 2

Comment: Worked for me as well, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Solution works for me is

**Before :**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','upload','form_validation','encrypt','pagination');
```

**After :**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','upload','form_validation','pagination');
```

i just removed encrypt library from autoload libraries.

Answer (score 1):

For php 7.2 version & Ubuntu system below commands works for me -

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

Then it will shows a message that "You should add extension for mcrypt in php.ini"

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

and restart the apache server

```
service apache2 restart
or
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to update your php version.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.requirements.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
Example: `sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
At line 1728, put this code:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

Then restart your Apache.

Comment: No improvement for me

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem so I placed this code into `/system/libraris/Encrypt.php` and now it is working fine.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * CodeIgniter Encryption Class
 *
 * Provides two-way keyed encoding using XOR Hashing and Mcrypt
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @category    Libraries
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html
 */
class CI_Encrypt {
    var $CI;
    var $encryption_key = '';
    var $_hash_type = 'sha1';
    var $_mcrypt_exists = FALSE;
    var $_mcrypt_cipher;
    var $_mcrypt_mode;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * Simply determines whether the mcrypt library exists.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->_mcrypt_exists = ( ! function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) ? FALSE : TRUE;
        log_message('debug', "Encrypt Class Initialized");
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Fetch the encryption key
     *
     * Returns it as MD5 in order to have an exact-length 128 bit key.
     * Mcrypt is sensitive to keys that are not the correct length
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function get_key($key = '')
    {
        if ($key == '')
        {
            if ($this->encryption_key != '')
            {
                return $this->encryption_key;
            }
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $key = $CI->config->item('encryption_key');
            if ($key == FALSE)
            {
                show_error('In order to use the encryption class requires that you set an encryption key in your config file.');
            }
        }
        return md5($key);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the encryption key
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  void
     */
    function set_key($key = '')
    {
        $this->encryption_key = $key;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Encode
     *
     * Encodes the message string using bitwise XOR encoding.
     * The key is combined with a random hash, and then it
     * too gets converted using XOR. The whole thing is then run
     * through mcrypt (if supported) using the randomized key.
     * The end result is a double-encrypted message string
     * that is randomized with each call to this function,
     * even if the supplied message and key are the same.
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string  the string to encode
     * @param   string  the key
     * @return  string
     */
    function encode($string, $key = '')
    {
        $key = $this->get_key($key);
        if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === TRUE)
        {
            $enc = $this->mcrypt_encode($string, $key);
        }
        else
        {
            $enc = $this->_xor_encode($string, $key);
        }
        return base64_encode($enc);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Decode
     *
     * Reverses the above process
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function decode($string, $key = '')
    {
        $key = $this->get_key($key);
        if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\+=]/', $string))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $dec = base64_decode($string);
        if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === TRUE)
        {
            if (($dec = $this->mcrypt_decode($dec, $key)) === FALSE)
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $dec = $this->_xor_decode($dec, $key);
        }
        return $dec;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Encode from Legacy
     *
     * Takes an encoded string from the original Encryption class algorithms and
     * returns a newly encoded string using the improved method added in 2.0.0
     * This allows for backwards compatibility and a method to transition to the
     * new encryption algorithms.
     *
     * For more details, see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html#encryption
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   int     (mcrypt mode constant)
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function encode_from_legacy($string, $legacy_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $key = '')
    {
        if ($this->_mcrypt_exists === FALSE)
        {
            log_message('error', 'Encoding from legacy is available only when Mcrypt is in use.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        // decode it first
        // set mode temporarily to what it was when string was encoded with the legacy
        // algorithm - typically MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        $current_mode = $this->_get_mode();
        $this->set_mode($legacy_mode);
        $key = $this->get_key($key);
        if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\+=]/', $string))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $dec = base64_decode($string);
        if (($dec = $this->mcrypt_decode($dec, $key)) === FALSE)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $dec = $this->_xor_decode($dec, $key);
        // set the mcrypt mode back to what it should be, typically MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
        $this->set_mode($current_mode);
        // and re-encode
        return base64_encode($this->mcrypt_encode($dec, $key));
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * XOR Encode
     *
     * Takes a plain-text string and key as input and generates an
     * encoded bit-string using XOR
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _xor_encode($string, $key)
    {
        $rand = '';
        while (strlen($rand) < 32)
        {
            $rand .= mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax());
        }
        $rand = $this->hash($rand);
        $enc = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $enc .= substr($rand, ($i % strlen($rand)), 1).(substr($rand, ($i % strlen($rand)), 1) ^ substr($string, $i, 1));
        }
        return $this->_xor_merge($enc, $key);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * XOR Decode
     *
     * Takes an encoded string and key as input and generates the
     * plain-text original message
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _xor_decode($string, $key)
    {
        $string = $this->_xor_merge($string, $key);
        $dec = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $dec .= (substr($string, $i++, 1) ^ substr($string, $i, 1));
        }
        return $dec;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * XOR key + string Combiner
     *
     * Takes a string and key as input and computes the difference using XOR
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _xor_merge($string, $key)
    {
        $hash = $this->hash($key);
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
        {
            $str .= substr($string, $i, 1) ^ substr($hash, ($i % strlen($hash)), 1);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Encrypt using Mcrypt
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function mcrypt_encode($data, $key)
    {
        $init_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_get_cipher(), $this->_get_mode());
        $init_vect = mcrypt_create_iv($init_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        return $this->_add_cipher_noise($init_vect.mcrypt_encrypt($this->_get_cipher(), $key, $data, $this->_get_mode(), $init_vect), $key);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Decrypt using Mcrypt
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function mcrypt_decode($data, $key)
    {
        $data = $this->_remove_cipher_noise($data, $key);
        $init_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->_get_cipher(), $this->_get_mode());
        if ($init_size > strlen($data))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $init_vect = substr($data, 0, $init_size);
        $data = substr($data, $init_size);
        return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt($this->_get_cipher(), $key, $data, $this->_get_mode(), $init_vect), "\0");
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Adds permuted noise to the IV + encrypted data to protect
     * against Man-in-the-middle attacks on CBC mode ciphers
     * http://www.ciphersbyritter.com/GLOSSARY.HTM#IV
     *
     * Function description
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _add_cipher_noise($data, $key)
    {
        $keyhash = $this->hash($key);
        $keylen = strlen($keyhash);
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0, $j = 0, $len = strlen($data); $i < $len; ++$i, ++$j)
        {
            if ($j >= $keylen)
            {
                $j = 0;
            }
            $str .= chr((ord($data[$i]) + ord($keyhash[$j])) % 256);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Removes permuted noise from the IV + encrypted data, reversing
     * _add_cipher_noise()
     *
     * Function description
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   type
     * @return  type
     */
    function _remove_cipher_noise($data, $key)
    {
        $keyhash = $this->hash($key);
        $keylen = strlen($keyhash);
        $str = '';
        for ($i = 0, $j = 0, $len = strlen($data); $i < $len; ++$i, ++$j)
        {
            if ($j >= $keylen)
            {
                $j = 0;
            }
            $temp = ord($data[$i]) - ord($keyhash[$j]);
            if ($temp < 0)
            {
                $temp = $temp + 256;
            }
            $str .= chr($temp);
        }
        return $str;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the Mcrypt Cipher
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   constant
     * @return  string
     */
    function set_cipher($cipher)
    {
        $this->_mcrypt_cipher = $cipher;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the Mcrypt Mode
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   constant
     * @return  string
     */
    function set_mode($mode)
    {
        $this->_mcrypt_mode = $mode;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Get Mcrypt cipher Value
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  string
     */
    function _get_cipher()
    {
        if ($this->_mcrypt_cipher == '')
        {
            $this->_mcrypt_cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
        }
        return $this->_mcrypt_cipher;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Get Mcrypt Mode Value
     *
     * @access  private
     * @return  string
     */
    function _get_mode()
    {
        if ($this->_mcrypt_mode == '')
        {
            $this->_mcrypt_mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
        }
        return $this->_mcrypt_mode;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Set the Hash type
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function set_hash($type = 'sha1')
    {
        $this->_hash_type = ($type != 'sha1' AND $type != 'md5') ? 'sha1' : $type;
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Hash encode a string
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function hash($str)
    {
        return ($this->_hash_type == 'sha1') ? $this->sha1($str) : md5($str);
    }
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Generate an SHA1 Hash
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function sha1($str)
    {
        if ( ! function_exists('sha1'))
        {
            if ( ! function_exists('mhash'))
            {
                require_once(BASEPATH.'libraries/Sha1.php');
                $SH = new CI_SHA;
                return $SH->generate($str);
            }
            else
            {
                return bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_SHA1, $str));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return sha1($str);
        }
    }
}
// END CI_Encrypt class
/* End of file Encrypt.php */
```

Comment: Won't it be reverted/current once composer is updated?

Answer (score -3):

with php 7 and above mcrypt need not to be loaded manually so both of the solution will work.

1. `$this->load->library('encrypt');`
   change to
   `$this->load->library('encrypt');`
2. Just remove encrypt from autoload

   `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','upload','form_validation','encrypt','pagination');`

Change to

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','upload','form_validation','encrypt','pagination');`