# The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a PHP application written using the Codeigniter framework. When I am trying to run this application on Windows Machine then I am getting below error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>   The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension.

This same application working fine on some random Windows Machine having the same configuration. I have tried on 5 different windows 10 machines and got this error on 3 Machine and worked fine on 2 machines. Here I have used the same installer to install XAMPP on all the machines and the same code, but still don't know how to make it run smoothly.
I have tried almost all the suggestions available online like to make a change in php.ini but no luck so far.

Comment: So, install (or enable) the extension. This is something you should have googled about.

Comment: Be aware that mcrypt was ***DEPRECEATED*** in version 7.1 of PHP and has been ***REMOVED*** from version 7.2 of PHP

Comment: I am using PHP Version 7.2.4
if possible could you please suggest the workaround to solve it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php error: The Encrypt library requires the Mcrypt extension in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798048/php-error-the-encrypt-library-requires-the-mcrypt-extension-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 15):

(FOR CI USERS only) If you are switched from CI2 XAMPP(php5) to XAMPP(php7) then, paste [encrypt.php](https://github.com/kpushpendra81/exam/blob/master/encrypt.php) in CI->system->libraries folder, after this it should be fine !

Comment: It works also for non-XAMPP configurations, but I did not copy the file but based on it I made the appropriate corrections on the side of my application.

Comment: This has worked but I could not tell what you changed because this file exists in the folder. Just replaced its content.

Answer (score 11):

For the future comers, I have face this problem too. It is usually issue with php 7.2.

Simply replace `encrypt` with `encryption` in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', 'encrypt', 'pagination');

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'email', 'session', '**encryption**', 'pagination');
```

Answer (score 4):

To **codeigniter** developers: some **CI** releases do not have **encrypt** listed in **autoload**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

Instead, they are loaded under **CI_Controller** derived controllers.

Search for

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
```

and replace with:

```
$this->load->library('encryption');
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux where PHP 5.6 or less...

`apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

Answer (score 0):

After replace Encrypt.php's Pushpendra Kumar, don't forget to set : 
 `$config['encryption_key'] = 'encryption_key';`

Answer (score 0):

INstall extention from here https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.3/windows

use TS version ..

put php_mcrypt.dll file into ../php/ext/

Answer (score 0):

you can bypass mbstring by just disabling

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
```

in config.php file.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following code to check if the mccrypt is enabled in your PHP Settings.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

By default, it is enabled on some server so that's why it is working on the random machine.

The quickest method to enable php-mcrypt on windows server – all you need to do is:

- Find php.ini (main php configuration file)
- Open and search for;extension=php_mcrypt.dll )
- Uncomment/remove “;” and save the php.ini

Comment: mccrypt is not enabled on the machine where i am getting error.
So, do i need to enable it ? if so then how ?

Comment: Could you please give me the steps to make it enable

Comment: If you have access to the php.ini file
you should be able to enable it.  you probably have to uncomment
a line within the php.ini refering to it by removing the ; before that line.

Comment: @RahulKumarSingh Updated answer for enabling extension.

Answer (score -1):

For Windows users

Autoload.php file will be as follows

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'encrypt', 'template', 'finediff', 'parser');

From the above remove encryption like below, after that restart apache services then it will works....

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'template', 'finediff', 'parser');

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem since you just removed the encryption libraries from the $autoload[libraries] array

Answer (score -1):

I was using PHP 7.2.xx version of php and followed the following steps:

> Mcrypt PECL extenstion

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

> Update the ini file with these commands:

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
```

> Verifying the installation:

```
php7.2-sp -i | grep mcrypt
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the result of the deprecation of Mycrypt extension. If you are using PHP > 7.1 and you need it you can follow the guidelines on this link  [Add mycrypt extension after PHP 7.1](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/issues/278#issuecomment-597018572)

Content from github link:

> 1-First, you should download the suitable version for your system from here:
> https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt/1.0.3/windows
>
> 2-Later, you should copy php_mcrypt.dll under ../xampp/php/ext/
>
> 3-you should enable extension like extension=mcrypt from
> xampp/php/php.ini
>
> personly I modified the php.ini file and i add this lines :
>
> extension=imap extension=mcrypt
>
> of course, these two lines have the 3 dll file saved on
> ../xampp/php/ext/ as :
>
> php_imap.dll php_mcrypt.dll